# Github API getting files data from directories

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, github-api

I'm trying to use the Github API in order to get contents of a directory I created.

This is the directory structure I have:

> - images
>
>   - mobile_images
>
>     - img1241251235
>
>       - extractedText.txt
>       - img.jpeg (these files might be larger then 1MB)
>     - img2142412312
>
>       - extractedText.txt
>       - img.jpeg

As you can see I know that in the `images/mobile_images/` directory there are a bunch of directories that follow a structure.

From these directories, I want to extract the content of each `extractedText.txt` file (the text stored in that file) and save the download_url of each `img.jpeg`.

The steps I follow are:

1. On the root directory (images/mobile_images) I call [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) method and get a list of the directories within it ([this response](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#response-if-content-is-a-directory)). So I get `img124...`, `img214...` and so on.
2. Now that I got all the directories (the `imgXX..` ones) I call the same method on each one to get their content. This returns the `extractedText.txt` and `img.jpeg`. (the response from step 1.)

So far so good.

Now if I call the same method on a file it should return [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#response-if-content-is-a-file). This works for the `extractedText.txt` files as their size is not bigger than 1 MB, but for the image files, it will throw an error.

I want to obtain a list of objects that will look like this:

```
Image(val name: String, //this is something I extract from img123...
val date: Long, //this is something I extract from img123...
val extractedText: String, //this should be the text from extractedText.txt
val url: String) //this should be the download_url of img.jpeg file
```

You can find my current code [here](https://gist.github.com/grrigore/ea97c0238ed2b5e73123c642898f5ee3).

Everything works fine until [that point](https://gist.github.com/grrigore/ea97c0238ed2b5e73123c642898f5ee3#file-code-kt-L26). When I reach the file I need to check if it's a text file or an image file.

The problem is that I don't know how to manage [that](https://gist.github.com/grrigore/ea97c0238ed2b5e73123c642898f5ee3#file-code-kt-L31) "if case" and after that merge the data I get (`download_url` and `extractedText content`) into a single image object. This is the part of the code I don't know how to approach:

```
// from here starts the problem 
 .flatMap(object:
  Function < ResponseBody, Observable < Any >> {
   override fun apply(responseBody: ResponseBody): Observable < Any > {
    return
    if (responseBody.path.contains("txt", true)) {
 // if the file is a text file I need to get the content of the file so I'll call this
     mModel.getFile(responseBody.path) as Observable < Any >
    } else {
 // as I mentioned if the file is an img I only need to get download_url
     responseBody.download_url
    }
   }
  })
 // merge the data into an Image file
 .toList()
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .subscribe(object: Consumer < MutableList < Image >> {
 // ...
```

1. Are there any easier ways to solve this problem?
2. Is my approach ok?
3. How can I handle that "if" situation and how can I merge the data into a single Image object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to implement a temporary solution.

I wrote two functions that will return:

1. [an `Observable` of the list](https://gist.github.com/grrigore/ea97c0238ed2b5e73123c642898f5ee3#file-solution-kt-L1) containing the data from the method `mModel.getFile(responseBody.path)`
2. [an `Observable` of the list](https://gist.github.com/grrigore/ea97c0238ed2b5e73123c642898f5ee3#file-solution-kt-L54) containing the `responseBody.download_url`

After I get the two observables I merge them using `.zip()` method with [this](https://gist.github.com/grrigore/ea97c0238ed2b5e73123c642898f5ee3#file-solution-kt-L97) combine method:

```
Observable.zip(getImageDataObservable(),
  getImageDownloadUrlObservable(),
  object: BiFunction < MutableList < Image > , MutableList < Image > , List < Image >> {
   override fun apply(imageData: MutableList < Image > , imageUrl: MutableList < Image > ): List < Image > {
    return combineImageObservables(imageData, imageUrl)
   }
  })
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .subscribe(object: Consumer < List < Image >> {
  override fun accept(images: List < Image > ? ) {
   Log.d(TAG, "images = ${images?.size}")
   Log.d(TAG, images.toString())

   if (images != null) {
    mViewDelegate.showImages(images)
   } else {
    mViewDelegate.showError("Try again!")
   }

   mViewDelegate.showSuccess("Displaying ${images?.size} images")
   mViewDelegate.hideLoading()
  }
 }, object: Consumer < Throwable > {
  override fun accept(t: Throwable ? ) {
   Log.e(TAG, t.toString(), t)
   if (t != null) {
    mViewDelegate.showError(t.message)
   } else {
    mViewDelegate.showError("Error")
   }
   Crashlytics.logException(t)
   mViewDelegate.hideLoading()
  }
 })
```